# Gensim word2vec model outputs 1000 dimension ndarray but the maximum number of ndarray dimensions is 32 - how?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/idio/wiki2vec/) 1000 dimension wikipedia word2vec model to analyze some documents.

Using introspection I found out that the vector representation of a word is a 1000 dimension numpy.ndarray, however whenever I try to create an ndarray to find the nearest words I get a value error:

```
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1000
```

and from what I can tell by looking around online 32 is indeed the maximum supported number of dimensions for an ndarray - so what gives? How is gensim able to output a 1000 dimension ndarray?

Here is some example code:

```
doc = [model[word] for word in text if word in model.vocab]
out = []
n = len(doc[0])
print(n)
print(len(model["hello"]))
print(type(doc[0]))
for i in range(n):
    sum = 0
    for d in doc:
        sum += d[i]
    out.append(sum/n)
out = np.ndarray(out)
```

which outputs:

```
1000
1000
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
ValueError: maximum supported dimension for an ndarray is 32, found 1000
```

The goal here would be to compute the average vector of all words in the corpus in a format that can be used to find nearby words in the model so any alternative suggestions to that effect are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `numpy`'s `ndarray()` constructor-function with a list that has 1000 numbers in it – your hand-calculated averages of each of the 1000 dimensions.

The `ndarray()` function expects its argument to be the *shape* of the matrix constructed, so it's trying to create a new matrix of shape `(d[0], d[1], ..., d[999])` – and then every individual value inside that matrix would be addressed with a 1000-int set of coordinates. And, indeed `numpy` arrays can only have 32 independent dimensions.

But even if you reduced the list you're supplying to `ndarray()` to just 32 numbers, you'd still have a problem, because your 32 numbers are floating-point values, and `ndarray()` is expecting integral counts. (You'd get a `TypeError`.)

Along the approach you're trying to take – which isn't quite optimal as we'll get to below – you really want to create a *single vector* of 1000 floating-point dimensions. That is, 1000 cell-like values – **not** `d[0] * d[1] * ... * d[999]` separate cell-like values.

So a crude fix along the lines of your initial approach could be replacing your last line with either:

```
result = np.ndarray(len(d))
for i in range(len(d)):
    result[i] = d[i]
```

But there are many ways to incrementally make this more efficient, compact, and idiomatic – a number of which I'll mention below, even though the *best* approach, at bottom, makes most of these interim steps unnecessary.

For one, instead of that assignment-loop in my code just above, you could use Python's bracket-indexing assignment option:

```
result = np.ndarray(len(d))
result[:] = d  # same result as previous 3-lines w/ loop
```

But in fact, `numpy`'s `array()` function can essentially create the necessary `numpy`-native `ndarray` from a given list, so instead of using `ndarray()` at all, you could just use `array()`:

```
result = np.array(d)  # same result as previous 2-lines
```

But further, `numpy`'s many functions for natively working with arrays (and array-like lists) already include things to do averages-of-many-vectors in a single step (where even the looping is hidden inside very-efficient compiled code or CPU bulk-vector operations). For example, there's a `mean()` function that can average lists of numbers, or multi-dimensional arrays of numbers, or aligned sets of vectors, and so forth.

This allows faster, clearer, one-liner approaches that can replace your entire original code with something like:

```
# get a list of available word-vetors
doc = [model[word] for word in text if word in model.vocab]
# average all those vectors
out = np.mean(doc, axis=0)
```

(Without the `axis` argument, it'd average together all individual dimension-values , in all slots, into just one single final average number.)

Comment: You're right, I was misinterpreting the use of the constructor. I did know about np.mean but since I wasn't sure of what was going on with the data types I tried doing it manually to reduce the unknowns.